# Oracle destination in SSIS data flow is failing with Error- ORA-01405: fetched column value is NULL

Tags: oracle, ssis, null, bulk-load, attunity

I have one SSIS package in which there is one DFT. In DFT, I have one Oracle source and one Oracle destination. 
In Oracle destination I am using Data Access Mode as **'Table Name - Fast Load (Using Direct Path)'**
There is one strange issue with that. It is failing with the following error

> [Dest  1 [251]] Error: Fast Load error encountered during
>   PreLoad or Setup phase. Class:    OCI_ERROR Status:   -1  Code:   0 Note: 
>      At:        ORAOPRdrpthEngine.c:735 Text:   ORA-00604: error occurred at
>   recursive SQL level 1 ORA-01405: fetched column value is NULL

I thought it is due to NULL values in source but there is no NOT NULL constraint in the destination table, so it should not be an issue. And to add into this, the package is working fine in case of **'Normal Load'** but **'Fast Load'**.

I have tried using NVL in case of NULL values from source but still no luck.

I have also recreated the DFT with these connections but that too in vain.

Can some one please help me with this?

Comment: Was the 'keep null' button selected at the OLE DB destination? Try it with 'keep null' selected or unselected

Comment: @DenStudent I am using Oracle Destination (it is the requirement) instead of OLE DB destination...

Comment: It worked fine after recreating the table with the same script...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked fine after recreating the oracle table with the same script